# design for vehicle identification number (VIN)

Tags: sql, database-design

I've designed a few [Vehicle Identification Number (VIN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_Identification_Number#Components_of_the_VIN) decoders for different OEMs.  The thing about VIN numbers...despite being somewhat standardized, each OEM can overload the character position codes and treat them differently, add "extra" metadata (i.e. asterisks pointing to more data outside the VIN number), etc., etc.  Despite all that, I've been able to build several different OEM VIN decoders, and now I'm trying to build a GM VIN decoder, and it is giving me a headache.

The gist of the problem is that GM treats the vehicle attributes section (position 4,5,6,7) differently depending on whether it is a truck or a car.  Here is the breakdown:

### GM Passenger Car VIN breakdown

[image: GM Car VIN]

### GM Truck VIN breakdown

[image: GM Truck VIN]

Normally what I do is design my own crude `ETL` process to import the data into an RDMBS - each table roughly correlates with the major VIN breakdown.  For example, there will be a WMI table, EngineType table, ModelYear table, AssemblyPlant table, etc.  Then I construct a View that joins on some contextual data that may or not be gleaned directly from the character codes in the VIN number itself (e.g. some vehicle types only have certain vehicle engines).

To look up a VIN is simply a matter of querying the VIEW with each major character code position breakdown of the VIN string.  For example, an example VIN of *1FAFP53UX4A162757* breaks down like this in a different OEM's VIN structure:

```
| WMI | Restraint | LineSeriesBody | Engine | CheckDigit | Year | Plant | Seq   |
| 123 | 4         | 567            | 8      | 9          | 10   | 11    | 12-17 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1FA | F         | P53            | U      | X          | 4    | A     | ...   |
```

GM has thrown a wrench into this...depending on whether it is a car or truck, the character code positions mean different things.

Example of what I mean - each ASCII table below correlates somewhat to a SQL table. `etc..` means there is a whole lot of other columnar data

#### Passenger Car

Here's an example of position 4,5 (corresponds to **vehicle line/series**).  These really go together, the VIN source data doesn't really differentiate between position 4 and 5 despite the breakdown illustrated above.

```
| Code (45)| Line  | Series   | etc..
--------------------------------------
| GA       | Buick | Lacrosse | etc..
```

..and position 6 corresponds to **body style**

```
| Code (6) | Style         | etc..
--------------------------------------
| 1        | Coupe, 2-Door | etc..
```

#### Trucks

..but for trucks, the structure is completely different.  Consider position 4 stands on its own as **Grosse Vehicle Weight Restriction GVWR**.

```
| Code (4) | GVWR     | etc..
-------------------------------
| L        | 6000 lbs | etc..
```

..and positions 5,6 (**Chassis/Series**) now mean something similar to position 4,5 of passenger car:

```
| Code (56) | Line  | Series  | etc.. 
---------------------------------------
| RV        | Buick | Enclave | etc..
```

I'm looking for a crafty way to resolve this in the relational design.  I would like to return a common structure when a VIN is decoded -- if possible (i.e. not returning a different structure for cars vs. trucks)

Comment: Why would you want to return the same structure for different vehicle types. IMHO it would be better to return different data structures for cars, trucks, motorbikes, caravans, etc. as they are a different business domain. There are common elements that they all share (weight, number of wheels, colour, etc.) but you should model it on what is in the real world.

Comment: After having built a number of these, that model has worked fine until now.  This data is an anomaly in a larger collection of OEM VIN data, and so I am trying to design around the anomaly vs. redesign the whole data model for everything that is already built.

Comment: Having worked in this industry, first, asking a question like this on SO is way out of the ballpark.  VIN decoding in itself is a cottage industry and the reason is that the folks who know how to decode VINs properly charge for it.  I understand what your trying to do, but even if I had your answer, the real answer is that VINs are incredibly messy, they are a data problem, there is no VIN standard that doesn't have exceptions. Points for a specific question, but add to the end (for what year) and keep writing code.

Comment: would make a better blog post than an SO question

Comment: @stackmonster I can appreciate that..believe you me, but I have already built a number of working VIN decoders for Chrysler, Ford, etc.  I'm limiting the data to a specific model year set -- which limits the scope of the data messiness.  I just want to resolve a decent workaround for the 4-7 GM code issue.  This particular problem can't be unique to VIN numbers.  We basically have to decode a string where positions in the string may mean different things based on the values found in other positions in the string.  The crux of the issue is that the structure isn't consistent.

Comment: I dont know how you can be in the VIN decoding business if you dont know how to model the result.

Comment: @stackmonster kudos for the lucid, constructive and fantastically useful comment(s)

Comment: @zenocon, can you know prior to decoding and based on other positions (WMI?) whether you have a VIN for a truck or a car?

Comment: @GuillemVicens yes, based on values in other positions, you can know which type of vehicle it is.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your answer to my comment regarding if you can identify the type of vehicle by using other values, a possible approach could be to have a master table with the common fields and 2 detail tables, each one with the appropriate fields for either cars or trucks.

Approximately something like the following (here I am guessing WMI is the PK):

**Master table**

```
| WMI | Restraint | Engine | CheckDigit | Year | Plant | Seq   |

| 123 | 4         | 8      | 9          | 10   | 11    | 12-17 |
```

**Car detail table**

```
| WMI | Veh Line | Series | Body Type |
| 123 | 2        | 3      | 4         |
```

**Truck detail table**

```
| WMI | GWVR | Chassis  |Body Type |
| 123 | 7    | 8        | 9        |
```

Having this, you could use a unique select to retrieve the needed data like following:

```
Select *
  From
(
   Select M.*,
          C.*,
          Null GWVR,
          Null Chassis,
          Null Truck_Body_Type
     From Master_Table M
     Left Join Car_Table C
       on M.WMI = C.WMI
   Union
   Select M.*,
          Null Veh_Line,
          Null Series,
          Null Car_Body_Type
          T.*
     From Master_Table M
     Left Join Truck_Table T
       on M.WMI = T.WMI
)
```

As for DML SQL you would only need to control prior to insert or update sentences whether you have a car or a truck model.

Of course you would need to make sure that only one detail exists for each master row, either on the car detail table or on the truck detail table.

HTH

Comment: thanks for taking the time to consider the problem (upvote for that).  It's not a bad suggestion, but I have come up with an alternative one, whereby I essentially merge positions 4,5,6 of car / truck into its own column.  I have a separate table for GVWR, BodyStyle, etc. with a linking table to each where the relationship exists.  This way I can still impose the common structure, and still match on VIN, but just doing string pattern matching easily on a view that aggregates all the data.

Comment: well, my suggestion was only one possibility to go after. Glad you got it working :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why you do not define both of these rules for the decoding; only one will resolve a valid result.